# odd missing right parethesis error in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this `where` clause in which when I try to save it, the "missing right parenthesis" error shows. The code goes like:

```
where
(
  (a.date is not null 
  and sysdate between b.date and b.date2
  and b.per_id is not null
  group by b.per_id)

or 
  (a.date is null
  and b.per_id is not null
  group by b.per_id)
)
```

the goal of this is to check when `a.date` is `null` then only output values that satisfiy `sysdate between b.date and b.date2` or else when `a.date` is `not null` then only output values that satisfiy `sysdate not between b.date and b.date2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group by` is a clause that *follows* the `where` clause.  It is not a condition.

So you want:

```
select . . .
from . . .
where (a.date is not null and
       sysdate between b.date and b.date2 and
       b.per_id is not null
      ) or 
      (a.date is null and
       b.per_id is not null 
      )
group by b.per_id
```